# Иерархия массива

Tags: jquery

Можно ли воссоздать иерархию в массиве?
К примеру такую:

```
Оружие
Виды
    Холодное
        Колюще-режущее
        Ударное
    Огнестрельное
        Пистолеты
        Дробовики
        Пистолеты-пулемёты
        Винтовки
        Пулемёты
        Снайперские винтовки
        Прочее
    Метательные
    Взрывчатка
Магазины
Патроны
Модули
    Глушители
    Прицелы
```

Comment: Ну... да, вайнот? Только хэш-мапе : `{"Оружие": null, "Виды": {"Холодное": {, ...}, ...}, ...}`.

Comment: А как к таким массивам "обращаться"?

Comment: `obj['Виды']['Холодное']['Колюще-режущее']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил такую структуру

```js
let wafen = {
  'Виды': {
    'Холодное': [
      'Колюще-режущее', 
      'Ударное'
    ],
    'Огнестрельное': [
      'Пистолеты',
      'Дробовики',
      'Пистолеты-пулемёты',
      'Винтовки',
      'Пулемёты',
      'Снайперские винтовки',
      'Прочее'
   ],
    'Метательные': [],
    'Взрывчатка': []
  },
  'Магазины': null,
  'Патроны': null,
  'Модули': {
    'Глушители': null,
    'Прицелы': null
  }
};

console.log(wafen.Виды.Огнестрельное[0]);
console.log(wafen.Виды.Огнестрельное[3]);
console.log(wafen.Виды.Холодное[1]);
```